# Onepage scroll effect

Tags: javascript, css

A few days ago i found this cool page http://www.google.com/glass/start/
Focus area is freezed when slide but others pages goes up and down by adding extra classes.
I found this demo http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html but its very different.

Does anyone know how to create this effect or some similar demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use, for example, fullPage.js:

http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/

Comment: This demo slide focus area i'm looking for something who slide divs :)

Comment: @user3097545 what do you mean with "the focus area" or the "slide focus"? If you are talking about the text, that's done with a fixed positioned element.